# não consigo inserir meu documento html em uma pag da web atraves do f12

Tags: html, link

Estou usando o F12 para tentar vincular ao link de uma pagina normal da web um de meus documentos html. Porém, ao inserir o link no href, a página diz não ter permissão para acessar o documento.
ex:(pag da web com tag "a" já existente)

```
<a href="file://casa/Users/BRUNO/Desktop/XTHML/stalin.html">
```

Comment: Explique melhor o que você está querendo/tentando fazer... E F12 em que contexto? No browser? Em algum editor?

Comment: é no Google Chrome, só pra exercitar a aula de links no html mesmo.